# cartopy problem with pcolormesh 'GeoAxesSubplot' object has no attribute '_hold'

Tags: matplotlib, cartopy

Just trying to learn cartopy, but can't even make a simple pcolormesh of wind gust data...

```
ax = plt.axes(projection = ccrs.LambertConformal())
cbax = ax.pcolormesh(gust['lon'], gust['lat'], gust['value'], 
                     transform = ccrs.PlateCarree())
```

I get the error **AttributeError: 'GeoAxesSubplot' object has no attribute '_hold'**

However, the contfourf plot does work...

```
cbax = ax.contourf(gust['lon'], gust['lat'], gust['value'], 
                   transform = ccrs.PlateCarree())
```

How do you make pcolormesh figures with cartopy?

Comment: You might be using matplotlib 3.0.0? In that case updating to 3.0.1 or 3.0.2 would solve this.

Comment: Updated to matplotlib 3.0.1 and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to configuring package versions, you might also would like to try the following code discussed [here](https://github.com/SciTools/cartopy/issues/1120).

```
from matplotlib.axes import Axes
from cartopy.mpl.geoaxes import GeoAxes
GeoAxes._pcolormesh_patched = Axes.pcolormesh
```

It worked for me at least. Hope this will be helpful.